# Confused about the substitution of the fermionic operators with their Fourier transform in an adiabatic Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, fourier-transform, fermions

In the section 4.1 of [Quantum Computation by Adiabatic Evolution](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0001106v1.pdf), Farhi et al proposes a quantum adiabatic algorithm to solve the $2$-SAT problem on a ring. To compute the complexity of the algorithm the authors computed the energy gap between the ground and first excited states of the 
adiabatic Hamiltonian.

The adiabatic Hamiltonian is defined as 
$$
\tilde{H} (s) = (1-s) \sum^n_{j=1}(1-\sigma^{(j)}_x) + s \sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{2} (1-\sigma^{(j)}_z \sigma^{(j+1)}_z )
$$

To prove the correctness of the algorithm, the authors consider an operator which negates the value of the bits in the $z$ axis.
$$
G = \prod^n_{j=1}\sigma^{(j)}_x
$$

Then the authors start the steps of Jordan-Wigner transformation. The fermionic operators are defined as follows.

$$
b_j = \sigma_x^1 \sigma_x^2 \ldots \sigma_x^{j-1} \sigma_-^{j} \mathbf{ 1}^{j+1} \ldots \mathbf{ 1}^n
\\
b^\dagger_j = \sigma_x^1 \sigma_x^2 \ldots \sigma_x^{j-1} \sigma_+^{j} \mathbf{ 1}^{j+1} \ldots \mathbf{ 1}^n
$$
where
$$
\sigma_{\pm} = \sigma_x \pm i \sigma_y
$$.

So, the adiabatic Hamiltonian can be reexpressed as follows.

$$
\tilde{H}(s) = \sum^n_{j=1} \left\{2 (1-s)b^\dagger_j b_j + \frac{s}{2}(1-(b^\dagger_j - b_j)(b^\dagger_{j+1} + b_{j+1}))\right\}
$$

After reexpressing the adiabatic Hamiltonian using the fermionic operators the authors takes the Fourier transform of the fermionic operators.

$$\beta_p =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{j=1} e^{i\pi p j/n} b_j$$
where $p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)$.

So,
$$
\left\{\beta_p, \beta_q\right\} = 0\\
\left\{\beta_p, \beta^\dagger_q\right\} = \delta_{pq}
$$

The Hamiltonian is then reexpressed as 
$$\tilde{H}(s) = \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} A_p (s)$$
where
$$
A_p (s) = 2 (1-s)[\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p + \beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta_{-p}] + s \left\{1 - \cos\frac{\pi p}{n} [\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p - \beta_{-p} \beta^\dagger_{-p}] + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n}[\beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta^\dagger_{p} - \beta_{p} \beta_{-p}]\right\}.
$$

**My confusion:**

It looks like $\sum^n_{j=1} b^\dagger_j b_j$ was replaced by $[\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p + \beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta_{-p}]$.  But I think a factor of $\frac{n}{2}$ is missing. I present my calculation as follows.

$$
\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p= \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum^n_{k=1}e^{-i\pi p k/n}b^\dagger_k\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum^n_{j=1}e^{i\pi p j/n}b_j\right)\\
=\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} b^\dagger_k b_j
$$

and

$$
\beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta_{-p}= \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{k=1} e^{i\pi p k/n} b^\dagger_k\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{j=1} e^{-i\pi p j/n} b_j\right)\\
=\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{i\pi p (k-j)/n} b^\dagger_k b_j
$$.

So, 
$$
\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p+\beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta_{-p}=\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1} b^\dagger_k b_j(e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} + e^{i\pi p (k-j)/n})\\
=\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1} b^\dagger_k b_j(2 \cos (-\pi p (k-j)/n))
\\
\sum^n_{j=1} b^\dagger_j b_j =\frac{n}{2}  (\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p+\beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta_{-p})/\cos (-\pi p (k-j)/n)
$$

This factor of $\frac{n}{2\cos (-\pi p (k-j)/n)} $ is missing in the substitution used in the paper.

Am I missing something?

Comment: When you expand $\beta^\dagger_p$ as a fourier series, take care to do two things. First, make sure you give your dummy labels different names (instead of naming them both $j$, try $k$ and $j$.) Once you have done that, make sure that you have the definition of the kronecker delta correct -- hint: there could be a factor of $n$ lurking in there.

Comment: @oscarafone, I have updated the labels accordingly. Could you please give more hint about how to define the Kronecker delta?

Comment: Kronecker delta is a short hand way of expressing vector dot products. In 3D    Euclidean space it is defined as $\delta_{ij}~(i,j=1,2,3)$, which is 1 when $i=j$ and zero when $i \neq j$.

Comment: @OmarShehab Look at the sum $\sum_{k,j = 1}^n \exp\left[i\pi p (k-j)/n\right]$. What does this equal when $k=j$? What does this equal when $k\neq j$?

Comment: @oscarafone, this is a spin chain on a ring. So, when $k=j$, $\sum_{k,j = 1}^n \exp\left[i\pi p (k-j)/n\right] = 1$. On the other hand, because it is a ring $k-j$ is either $1$ or $-1$. So, $\sum_{k,j = 1}^n \exp\left[i\pi p (k-j)/n\right] = \sum_{k,j = 1}^n \exp\left[\pm i\pi p/n\right]$.

Comment: @OmarShehab When $k=j$ you have simply $\sum_{k=1}^n \times 1$. What is this equal to?

Comment: @oscarafone, that's $n$ when $k = j$. I missed that in my previous comment. So, now I understand this $n$ cancels out $1/n$. If $j = k$,  $\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p+\beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta_{-p}=\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1} b^\dagger_k b_j(e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} + e^{i\pi p (k-j)/n}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{j=1} b^\dagger_j b_j(1 + 1) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{j=1} b^\dagger_j b_j(1 + 1) = \frac{1}{n} (\sum^n_{j=1} 2)(\sum^n_{j=1}  b^\dagger_j b_j) = 2 \sum^n_{j=1}  b^\dagger_j b_j$. So, $n$ is taken care of but there is still a factor of $2$ missing in the paper's calculation. What do we do if $j \ne k$?

Comment: @OmarShehab the sum is a kronecker delta $n\delta_{jk}$. So if $j\neq k$ the sum is zero. About where the factor of two comes from, I can't look over it at the moment. I can suggest combing over your work another time and looking for that factor of two (if the paper is, in fact, correct.)